# Using Google Lighthouse with multiple sites simultaneously in a script

Tags: node.js, webdriver, lighthouse, lighthouse-ci

I need to use lighthouse to generate report for hundreds of websites, so i want to write a script (golang, nodejs or whatever) to do that.

Is there a way to run multiple website analyze from one chrome-driver instance with Lighthouse or do i need to run n chrome driver to do so ?

Otherwise, did exist an alternative to google lighthouse for SEO checking and optimization ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after research :

I've found github projects for multiple sites processing with lighthouse but there's not really what i need.

[Here](https://github.com/Carr1005/lighthouse-batch-parallel#lighthouse-batch-parallel)'s the best match for me, but as said in [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/7104#issuecomment-458368476) issue; it's not recommended to use Lighthouse concurrently.

Edit :
After more researchs, i can affirm there's no good methods to run lighthouse concurrently in the same computer.

The best solution would be to use [lasso](https://github.com/google/lasso) or [lighthouse lambda parallel](https://github.com/stuartsan/lighthouse-lambda-parallel) for cloud computing, but i'm not a big fan of google & aws services, but i can sell my soul for money, so...